# How to debaunce search query in react-router v6.4.3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

I have a search input that updates the query parameter and triggering the API call in react-router loader for that specific route on every onChange event.
How I could prevent calling the API on every keystroke and implement something like debounce effect(when user is not typing for 1000ms then call the API or update the query parameter).
**NOTE**: I know there is a debounce hook and logic but I'm interested if it is possible to achieve with the react-router only.

component where I have update query params logic:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const countryQuery = searchParams.get("country") || "";

  const handleOnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setSearchParams(
      { country: event.target.value }
    );
  };
```

loader:

```
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const countryQuery = url.searchParams.get("country") || "";

  const countries = getCountries(countryQuery);

  return countries;
};
```

I would like to prevent unnecessary API calls.

Comment: I was thinking, if you can lift state up to the parent or use a context to trigger the udpates,  can you share some more relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can try using debounce from lodash

```
import { debounce, filter, get, join, map } from 'lodash';
```

Simpler version which uses on the setter

```
  const debouncedOnChange = useCallback(
         debounce((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            setSearchParams(
               { country: event.target.value }
            );

         }, 300), []);
```

If you need to refer other varaibles in handle search, you can useRef

```
const handleOnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setSearchParams(
      { country: event.target.value }
    );
};

  const searchRef = useRef(handleOnChange);
  searchRef.current = handleOnChange;

  const debouncedOnChange = useCallback(debounce(searchRef.current, 300), []);
```

you can try use `debouncedOnChange` in place of handleOnChange

Hope it helps you

Comment: Just for information, what's the point of `useRef` there ?

Comment: Actually useRef is not needed in this case, it should be used when reference to the latest version of the varaibles, function is needed, without adding them to the dependency array, Ill include an simpler version in the answer